# Nullreference exception - why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Panel pnl_Confirmation = (Panel)form1.FindControl("ConfirmationPanel") as Panel;
    pnl_Confirmation.Visible = false;
```

I keep getting a "NullReferenceException" in the above code.  "ConfirmationPanel" is a panel I show/hide depending on if the form is submitted successfully or not.

The panel is wrapped in a LoginView control, which is why I cannot call "ConfirmationPanel" directly:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
<LoggedInTemplate> 
<asp:Panel id="ConfirmationPanel" runat="server" Wrap="False">
```

...

Why is this null?  It should be referencing the Panel with the ID "ConfirmationPanel", no?

Thanks

Comment: `Panel pnl_Confirmation = (Panel)form1.FindControl("ConfirmationPanel") as Panel;` Why are you casting twice?

Comment: This may not be the sort of comment you want, but is there any way you can work with MVC instead? ASP.NET webforms is concentrated evil.

Comment: You don't need both types of type casts: "as Panel" is sufficient.

Comment: is the panel visible for the first time when you execute the statement Panel pnl_Confirmation = (Panel)form1.FindControl("ConfirmationPanel") as Panel; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Panel pnl_Confirmation = LoginView1.FindControl("ConfirmationPanel") as Panel;
if(pnl_Confirmation != null)
   pnl_Confirmation.Visible = false;
```

Comment: This worked.  Thanks!  It seems I was casting twice, as well as referencing from "form1" instead of "LoginView1".

Answer (score 2):

It all depends where you have that code. If you have it before Page_Load(), the control tree is probably not built yet, hence the null reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use the FindControl of **LoginView** instead

```
Panel pnl_Confirmation = LoginView1.FindControl("ConfirmationPanel") as Panel;
```

Because it's part of the LoginView template.

Answer (score 1):

"FindControl will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls. " (from the MSDN documentation)

i.e. call FindControl on LoginView or create a recursive FindControl

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to typecast twice.

Try to only typecast once with either works best:

```
Panel pnl_Confirmation = (Panel)form1.FindControl("ConfirmationPanel");
```

or

```
Panel pnl_Confirmation = form1.FindControl("ConfirmationPanel") as Panel;
```

It is also important to verify whether your reference is not null before trying to access it

```
if (pnl_Confirmation != null)
    pnl_Confirmation.Visible = false;
```